# How to run docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud on windows through LAN only

Tags: windows, nginx, docker, nextcloud

As the title suggests, I am trying to run **nextcloud** with **OnlyOffice** in **Docker Desktop for Windows**, and I am trying to congfigure **nginx** to accept connections through **LAN**, such that I can connect to my server from other computers on the network, all of which are running **Windows 10**.

Though I have read through many posts around the internet with similar issues, none of them seem to have my particular setup, and I am unable to figure out what to do from here.

**What I have managed to do so far:**

**1-** Installed **docker engine for windows community edition**. I am using Docker's default containers.

**2-** Installed **docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud** using the instructions on the github page here:

https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud

**3-** I can now access nextcloud on **http://localhost/** on the **host computer** but I have had no luck connecting to it from any other computer on the network.

**Problem:**

I am unable to figure out what is preventing me from connecting to the server locally, but I am guessing that it has something to do with the **nginx server configuration**.

For reference, below are the configuration files and scripts used for this setup:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app-server
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '80'
      - '9000'
    volumes:
      - app_data:/var/www/html
  onlyoffice-document-server:
    container_name: onlyoffice-document-server
    image: onlyoffice/documentserver:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '80'
      - '443'
    volumes:
      - document_data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data
      - document_log:/var/log/onlyoffice
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx-server
    image: nginx
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - app_data:/var/www/html
volumes:
  document_data:
  document_log:
  app_data:
  mysql_data:
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    upstream backend {
      server app-server:9000;
    }


    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $http_host $this_host {
        "" $host;
        default $http_host;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $the_scheme {
        default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        "" $scheme;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_host $the_host {
       default $http_x_forwarded_host;
       "" $this_host;
    }

    server {
    listen 80;

        # Add headers to serve security related headers
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;

        root /var/www/html;
        client_max_body_size 10G; # 0=unlimited - set max upload size
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        gzip off;

        index index.php;
        error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
        error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav/ permanent;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location / {
            rewrite ^/remote/(.*) /remote.php last;
            rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    location ~* ^/ds-vpath/ {
        rewrite /ds-vpath/(.*) /$1  break;
                proxy_pass http://onlyoffice-document-server;
                proxy_redirect     off;

                client_max_body_size 100m;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $the_host/ds-vpath;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $the_scheme;
        }

        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_pass backend;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the location ~ \.php(?:$|/) { block
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|swf)$ {
            access_log off;
        }

    }
}
```

**set_configuration.sh**

````
set -x

docker exec -u www-data app-server php occ --no-warnings config:system:get trusted_domains >> trusted_domain.tmp

if ! grep -q "nginx-server" trusted_domain.tmp; then
    TRUSTED_INDEX=$(cat trusted_domain.tmp | wc -l);
    docker exec -u www-data app-server php occ --no-warnings config:system:set trusted_domains $TRUSTED_INDEX --value="nginx-server"
fi

rm trusted_domain.tmp

docker exec -u www-data app-server php occ --no-warnings app:install onlyoffice

docker exec -u www-data app-server php occ --no-warnings config:system:set onlyoffice DocumentServerUrl --value="/ds-vpath/"
docker exec -u www-data app-server php occ --no-warnings config:system:set onlyoffice DocumentServerInternalUrl --value="http://onlyoffice-document-server/"
docker exec -u www-data app-server php occ --no-warnings config:system:set onlyoffice StorageUrl --value="http://nginx-server/"```


  [1]: https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/docker-onlyoffice-nextcloud
````

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you try to access it from another computer?

Comment: "This site can’t be reached192.168.XX.XX took too long to respond." is what im getting. This message is displayed in chrome, or something similar in firefox. Note that by access I mean through a web browser as a client and not as an admin through some CLI.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. Make sure you configured the windows firewall correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this turned out to be the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is in windows firewall, then try disabling it and testing the connection to see if it works. If it does work, reactivate windows firewall, and then you can proceed to follow the instructions below:

1- Click Start and Type **Windows Firewall** on your host PC.

2- Click on **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**.

3- Find **Inbound Rules** on the left side of the window, and right click it.

4- Click **New Rule..** and a new window will come up.

5- Choose **Port** on the **Rule Type** tab, then click **Next**.

6- Under the **Protocol and Ports** tab, choose **TCP** in the first choice, and **Specific Local Ports:** in the second choice, and type in **80** in the text box. Click **Next**.

7- Under the **Action** tab, choose **Allow the Connection**.

8- Under the **Profile** tab, select Check all boxes and click **Next**.

9- Under the **Name** tab, give your rule a name, and type in a small description of what it is so you can remember why you created it. Click **Finish**.

This rule should now be active, and you should be able to connect to your server by typing in its IP Address on another machine on the same network.

Note that I am by no means informed enough on the subject matter and that I am learning as I go. I am using this package of software for personal tasks and to learn, so security is not a big issue for me, and I have no idea how bad this "solution" of mine is from an expert's point of view.

**So Please Proceed With Caution.**

Source: https://www.nextofwindows.com/allow-server-running-inside-wsl-to-be-accessible-outside-windows-10-host

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: As requested, and Thanks again.